# Design Pattern for Context-sensitive representation

Tags: java, design-patterns

**Question**

*Is there a design pattern that allows me to create a context-sensitive representations of classes?*

**Definition**

*Representation*: the available getters, and the values they return.

*Context*: the request context of the object.

**Example**

A site publishes houses for sale.

A guest user has `House.getPrice()`, which returns 100,000 for house X.

A registered user has `House.getPrice()`, which returns 95,000 for house X.

A registered user has `House.getLandLordEmail()`, which the guest user doesn't have.

**Purpose**

The practical use of this a Rest-service, to make use of automated mappings to XML/JSON with JAX-B.

**Note**

I'm not asking for code to implement this. I just want to know if there is a design pattern for this and what it is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that both the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) apply nicely.

For example, here's a [discussion of pricing models using strategies](http://www.adamtornhill.com/Patterns%20in%20C%203,%20STRATEGY.pdf).

[image]

Comment: yeah decorators would be a good approach here I think. Combined with a factory for producing the concrete types you could keep concerns nicely separated

Comment: I don't understand how the Strategy Pattern applies, but I agree that decorator looks very promising (and actually a lot like what I had in mind already)

Comment: Strategy can be applied for price caculations based on different pricing models.

Answer (score 2):

why can't you have a `HouseFactory` or similar which produces `IHouse` implmentations. Then you can have implementations like `RegisteredUserHouse` and `GuestUserHouse` which encapsulate the logic you describe.

Then just choose the implementation to return from the factory based on whether the user is registered or not.

Comment: Very practical and easy to implement.

Comment: It seems strange to me that the House-on-sale domain model (which is a model of a real world concept) is so tightly coupled to User registration state (which is a concept of internet marketing). Aren't those two unrelated domain concepts you're mixing in your `RegisteredUserHouse` and `GuestUserHouse` classes?

Comment: @SergeyPetunin I was only suggesting an approach and giving an example of how it might work. the names of the classes are examples, and probably not realistic. It seems strange to me that registered users get a discount for a house. to save 5000 on buying a house I'd join a web site. Maybe this is a model for something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to solve two different tasks here.

When you need to show the user only partial information about the house based on if the user is registered or not, then you should do this in the presentation layer (when generating your interface and applying security constraints), and not drag this into your domain layer.

When you need to apply a certain price or discount strategy depending on whether user is registered or not, this seems like a domain layer problem, and should be tackled with Strategy pattern.